# Fast display of raw pixel data from byte[] .net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, graphics, compact-framework, raster

I'm playing with rasters and I want to know the fastest way to paint a byte[] to the screen using the .net CF.  The array is a standard 24bit raster (Screen.Width * Screen.Height * 3 in length, RGB order) and right now I'm saving the array to a Bitmap object and drawing it to the screen using the Graphics.DrawImage(bmp) method.  I feel that there must be someway of doing this w/o having to create a Bitmap.

I'm using C#, but I can to go native if needs be (I'd prefer P/Invokes if possible, assuming that is the case)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use unsafe c# pointers to 'fill' the bitmap. This should give a huge speedup.

Comment: Do you have an example?  I'm curious about how to do this... Unsafe is my middle name! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When drawing images, I found the native `BitBlt` to perform alot better than using .NET `Graphics`, you could use it to display your `Bitmap` or even use GDI to create the bitmap instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923590.aspx

An example of using `BitBlt` in .NET CF (although it's the reverse of what you are doing, and in VB.NET):

http://anoriginalidea.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/getting-a-screenshot-using-vbnet-on-the-compact-framework-20/

Comment: So I need to create a bitmap no matter what?  I can't have direct access to frame buffer?

Comment: I don't think a bitmap (a native one created by `CreateBitmap`) is alot more than a block of pixel data really, of course you'll need to conform to GDI's format. And I don't think you can present a bitmap faster than `Bitblt` while staying device independent.

Comment: Say I wanted to go with DIBs because they are alloc'd in the user's memory heap instead of the GWES's heap.  What would my options be then?  And how would I go about doing that?  Thanks for the answers btw :)